# Remove underline from link within hyperlinked div

Tags: html, css, href

I am using the html below

```
<a href=""><div class="logo"><span class="whologo">hyperlinked text </span>
</div></a>
```

the problem i am having is that the only way to remove underline from the span text is using `a:link{text-decoration:none;}` but this removes underlines from ALL links from the whole page

I have tried

```
a.logo:link{text-decoration:none;}
```

but it doesnt remove the hyperlink from the span element.

Comment: `a.logo` won't match because the `<a>` element does not have the `logo` class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong hierarchy there and bad element selection. In your case, the most accurate CSS would be:

```
a div.logo span.whologo {text-decoration:none;}
```

---

But I suggest this approach:

```
<div class="logo"><a href=""><span class="whologo">hyperlinked text </span></a>
```

And CSS:

```
div.logo a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Or include the span if needed (but only if the span element has underlines, like Hans pointed out in the comment):

```
div.logo a span.whologo {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: this wont work Shomz. This is because your browser will underline an `a` if you dont style it away... This only gives this span no underline, but thats not happening here

Comment: +1 Thank you! But that's why I said 'if needed'... wanted to give him the most accurate selection, yet I don't know what the rest of his CSS looks like. This was in case he somehow added the underline to the span element...

Comment: I actually started off with your answer too :) But then remembered the hidden styling browsers give to `a` elements!

Comment: It was a good point nevertheless. I think all this should help him tackle that CSS problem. :)

Comment: Haha, sure hope so, otherwise he should try a new hobby :)

Answer (score 3):

Child items cannot influence their parents using CSS. You need to put an ID or class name on your `A` tag, or find something unique up the tree that you can specify for this element.

Answer (score 2):

**Check this out**

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .linkTst{text-decoration:none;} 
    </style>

<div class="logo"><a href="" class="linkTst"><span class="whologo">hyperlinked text </span>
   </a> </div>
```

Comment: You wouldn't like to teach someone to do it like this, would you?

Comment: @Shomz sorry now check it out

Comment: Much better, you might also like to keep div elements outside of anchors - that's just a common practice, not sure it's considered invalid though.

Comment: @Shomz yes sir grateful to you,,check this out now,,and find my profile if you have time ,, tnks

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This is not valid html... And you should give your `a` a class or id, otherwise this isnt possible with remote css. It is possible with inline css...

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on your a tag where you don't want the underline

like this : http://jsfiddle.net/UL8SW/

Answer (score 0):

Give anchor tag a class.

HTML:

```
<a href="" class='no-underline'><div class="logo"><span class="whologo">hyperlinked text</span>
```

CSS:

```
.no-underline {text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: Why answer on a question that had an accepted answer from years ago?