# add glyphicon to rails link_to helper and disable effects when hovering

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style my link_to helper. I want to add an icon instead of a link and disable all the effects. I followed this method [Remove underline from link within hyperlinked div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282391/remove-underline-from-link-within-hyperlinked-div) but it did not work for me, whenever I hover over the icon it disappears which is not what I want. Here's what I have so far.

```
<div id = "owner-icons">
<%= link_to  product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  do %>    
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

bootstrap.css

```
div.owner-icons a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Is possible to change the color of the icon as well ?

Comment: you change color of icon, by adding css color attribute to it. <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red !important;"></span> OR div.owner-icons span {color:red !important;}

Comment: Thank you I was able to change the color.

Comment: Ok, good to hear. You could also change the color in bootstrap by changing parents color. Put a vote on my answer please))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simpy add `glyphicon` to you link like this:

**View** (help me change `your_url`)

```
<div id="owner-icons">
  <%= link_to  '', your_url, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash' %>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
#owner-icons a {
  color: red; # your custom color
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Btw, in your current code has some problems:

- `owner-icons` is `id` not `class`, so your css will not work
- `</div>` closing tag isn't in the right place I think

## Update

Add hover style to link:

- In case you are using scss

  ```
  #owner-icons a {
    color: red; # your custom color
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      background: transparent; # Your custom background
    }
  }
  ```
- Or a plain css

  ```
  #owner-icons a {
    color: red; # your custom color
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #owner-icons a:hover {
    background: transparent; # Your custom background
  }
  ```

Comment: It changed the color, but still whenever I hover over it, its background turns to black now, which means  text-decoration: none; is not working I guess ?

Comment: you may add hover style to your css, checkout my update!